# google drive listing files in public shared folder

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I have an authenticated google client and I am wanting to list files in someone else's public folder (i think the folder being shared or not is irrelevant since it is public)

Here is my code in NodeJS

```
  const drive      = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  let fconf        = {};
  fconf.maxResults = 10;
  fconf.orderBy    = "createdTime"; 
  fconf.driveId    = "xyz-badfd134343example";
  fconf.includeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
  fconf.q          = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";
  fconf.supportsTeamDrives = true; 
  fconf.corpa              = "drive";
  fconf.supportsAllDrives  = true;

  drive.files.list(fconf, function(e,d)
  {
    console.log("e,d",e,d);
  });
 }
```

note: there is no 'folderId' option in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list - just a driveId option

Although I set the corpa to "drive" and Drive Id, I get the following error

```
{ Error: The driveId parameter must be specified if and only if corpora is set to drive.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/c/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/c/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  response: 
   { config: 
      { url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId=examplexyz&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&corpa=drive&supportsAllDrives=true',
        method: 'GET',
        paramsSerializer: [Function],
        headers: [Object],
        params: [Object],
        validateStatus: [Function],
        responseType: 'json' },
     data: { error: [Object] },
     headers: 
      { 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000',
        'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
        connection: 'close',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        date: 'Thu, 24 Oct 2019 00:38:10 GMT',
        expires: 'Thu, 24 Oct 2019 00:38:10 GMT',
        server: 'GSE',
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block' },
     status: 403,
     statusText: 'Forbidden' },
  config: 
   { url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?driveId=examplexyz&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&corpa=drive&supportsAllDrives=true',
     method: 'GET',
     paramsSerializer: [Function],
     headers: 
      { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
        Authorization: 'Bearer something',
        Accept: 'application/json' },
     params: 
      { driveId: 'examplexyz',
        includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
        corpa: 'drive',
        supportsAllDrives: true },
     validateStatus: [Function],
     responseType: 'json' },
  code: 403,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'teamDriveIdRequiresTeamDriveCorpora',
       message: 'The driveId parameter must be specified if and only if corpora is set to drive.' } ] } undefined
close the queue { success: true }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the file list from the publicly-shared folder.

  - You want to retrieve only Spreadsheet files.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to retrieve the file list with the method of files.list of Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, in order to retrieve the file list from the publicly shared folder, the search query of your script is modified.

  - The search query of `'folderId' in parents` returns the file list in the folder.

#### Modified script:

```
const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID of the publicly shared folder.

const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
let fconf = {};
fconf.maxResults = 10;
fconf.orderBy = "createdTime";
fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'`;
drive.files.list(fconf, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.data);
  }
});
```

- If you want to retrieve the file list of all files in the publicly shared folder, please use `'${folderId}' in parents` as the search query.

#### Note:

- In above modified script, when the folder is not yours and not shared publicly, the file list cannot be retrieved from the folder. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

When the folder ID you provided is used for the script, how about the following script? In this case, 8 folders can be seen in the retrieved file list.

#### Sample script:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
const folderId = "0B3d5a94e071mfjN6S19MeGZZYi1hWHNfeFlPWVdqS3RMWXhXMnhJeHhmdU91WWlwWjdCN1U";
let fconf = {};
fconf.maxResults = 10;
fconf.orderBy = "createdTime";
fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents`;
drive.files.list(fconf, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: first class response. i am getting 200 response now, unfortunately the data.files is an empty array []. any thoughts? the publicly available drive url is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3d5a94e071mfjN6S19MeGZZYi1hWHNfeFlPWVdqS3RMWXhXMnhJeHhmdU91WWlwWjdCN1U

Comment: @user1709076 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I checked the folder you provided with the query of `'folderId' in parents`, it was found that the mimeType of all files was `text/csv`. So please try the query of ``fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents and mimeType = 'text/csv'`;`` or ``fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents`;``.

Comment: yes, trying fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents` - i dont know why i get an empty file array data: { kind: 'drive#fileList', incompleteSearch: false, files: [] } - seems to be an empty file array no matter what public folder i choose, for example: fconf.q = `'0B3d5a94e071mfjN6S19MeGZZYi1hWHNfeFlPWVdqS3RMWXhXMnhJeHhmdU91WWlwWjdCN1U' in parents`;

Comment: @user1709076 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize again. About the folder ID, it was found that `0B3d5a94e071mfjN6S19MeGZZYi1hWHNfeFlPWVdqS3RMWXhXMnhJeHhmdU91WWlwWjdCN1U` is different from the initial folder ID of `1IRg7eNuHNc7wmLkbpk__mNWc-MNtovLd` you commented. In the case of current folder ID, all files are the folders. So you can retrieve the file list with `fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents`;`. But I'm not sure about your current script. So I added the sample script for the folder ID you provided to my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: the scope of my google drive app has 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' - which i would think would be enough event hough the scope is for files 'created by my app' - i dont think there is an option or need to have an additional scope to list publicaly available files?

Comment: @user1709076 I think that reason of your issue might be due to the scope. Please try the following scope. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata`. At that time, please delete the token file and reauthorize again.

Comment: thank you. yes you are right, by using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly I am able to view other people's publicly available drive files - although i do not understand since the permission asks to view 'all files that you own' when accepting. The https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly option was the least aggressive policy out of the options. Thank you for your kindness in answering this question - I would like to accept your response.

Comment: @user1709076 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.